# If a product of polynomials converges, does some product of their zeros also converge?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Suppose $\{p_k\}$ is a sequence of polynomials with $p_k(0)=1$.  Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ be an enumeration of all of the zeros of the $p_k$.  Suppose that 
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k(z)$$
converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.  Is there some permutation $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$f_\sigma (z)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z}{a_{\sigma(k)}}\right)$$
converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$?

This is a follow-up to [Factoring a convergent infinite product of polynomials.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840212/factoring-a-convergent-infinite-product-of-polynomials), in which an example of such $\{p_k\}$ is given along with a permutation $\sigma$ for which the product $f_\sigma (z)$ does $\underline{\text{not converge}}$.

Comment: Since you have $a_{\sigma(k)}$ in a denominator, you probably don't want to include $0$ in your enumeration of the zeros, even though it is a zero of all the $p_k$.

Comment: Thank you. I meant $p_k(0)=1$.

Comment: My intuition is telling me that the answer is definitely "no". But I need to think more.

Comment: I think this is true, but possibly not that easy to prove. It might be provable with a product version of the "polygonal confinement theorem" by Steinitz: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/levy.pdf

Comment: @LukasGeyer Do you know if there is an analog of something like Lemma 3.1 in the paper you linked for holomorphic functions?  Something like:  if $f_1,...,f_m$ are analytic on $|z|\leq R$, $ \left\| \sum_{n=1}^m f_n \right\|_{|z|\leq R}< \epsilon$ and $ \|f_n\|_{|z|\leq R} < \epsilon$, then there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $1,2,\ldots,m$ such that whenever $1\leq j\leq m$,
$$\left\| \sum_{n=1}^j f_{\sigma(n)} \right\|_R< 4\epsilon.$$

Comment: @user122916: I don't know, but that is a natural and interesting question. I have not really thought about it, no idea how easy or hard it is.

Comment: I can prove the original question in the affirmative if I can prove the above analog.  Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: For what it's worth, some version of the analog I mentioned above appears to be implied by Lemma 7 and its ensuing Corollary in  [this paper](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0403?tify={%22pages%22:[200],%22panX%22:0.661,%22panY%22:1.044,%22view%22:%22export%22,%22zoom%22:0.673}) by Banasczcyk.  The paper is a generalization of the Levy-Steinitz theorem to nuclear spaces.  As I am unfamiliar with nuclear spaces, it will take some time for me to pursue this avenue further.  But it looks promising.